# Image classifier does not generalize well to slight image perturbations

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN to classify a 28x28 rgb image into 200 categories.
The classifier reaches ~95% accuracy on the train set.
The test images are obtained by taking a screenshot, cropping and resizing the roi to 28x28.
This image processing causes a slight difference in the train and test images (example attached).
Even though the difference is almost imperceptible to the human eye it causes a huge drop in accuracy for my classifier.
My classifier reaches up to 95% accuracy on the train set but only ~10% on the test set.
I started applying random perturbations to the training images (blur, pixelation, noise, translation, scaling) and started blurring the test images but test accuracy only barely improved.

How can I make my classifier robust so that it generalizes over slight pixel differences?

Here is my network

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, img_size[0], img_size[1], 3], name='input')

conv1 = relu(batch_normalization(
    conv_2d(network, 16, 3, bias=False, activation=None, regularizer="L2"), trainable=is_training))

conv2 = relu(batch_normalization(
    conv_2d(conv1, 32, 3, bias=False, activation=None, regularizer="L2"), trainable=is_training))

conv3 = relu(batch_normalization(
    conv_2d(conv2, 64, 3, bias=False, activation=None, regularizer="L2"), trainable=is_training))

net = fully_connected(conv3, 128, activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
net = fully_connected(net, num_elements, activation='softmax')

return regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=learning_rate,
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='target')
```

Train image:
[image: Train image]
Test image
[image: Test image]

Comment: Is your training set coming from the same source? If it is not, it may be the issue.

Comment: No it's not. I have access to high resolution training images which I preprocess and resize for training. Compare this to screenshotting, cropping and resizing for the test images. Obviously train and test will be different after this but because the difference is so tiny and they look so similar I thought i could still make it work.

Comment: You seem to have overfitted the model. Did you do cross-validation? (You should.)

Comment: Train and valid strongly diverge even after the first epoch. The model is definitely overfitting I know that. My question is how to I stop that and encourage it to generalize better.

Answer (score 0):

200 categories is a lot. Are you sure something is not dominating the other classes, e.g. the model is not guessing 'background' all the time and being right 95% of the time just because 95% of the images are 'background'?

[Pooling](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html) (p. 335 onwards), by for example max pooling, is one way to introduce invariance to small transformations. You should try it out.
Other ways to limit overfit are by tuning that L2 regularization you are already using, to add dropout to the fully connected layer and to not have a too big minibatch size. You could add also small rotations to the list of augmentations you are doing, if you find it appropriate. Maybe random reflections too, if you expect that to happen in the real world? I don't think it's about the augmentation though.

And finally my personal favourite : human error. Usually when I see something this odd it was just my own fault. You should go through the code and intermediate variables again, more than once.